# Find root of numerical integration

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, physics, numerical-integration

I am trying to reproduce this Mathematica program in Python:

[image: Mathematica program]

It finds the roots of an numerical integration, and forms a plot of these values. However, I cannot get my attempt to run.

Current attempt:

from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

```
# Variables.
boltzmann_const = 1.38e-23
planck_const = 6.62e-34
hbar = planck_const / ( 2 * np.pi )
transition_temp = 9.2
gap_energy_at_zero_kelvin = 3.528 / ( 2 * transition_temp * boltzmann_const )
debye_freq = ( 296 * boltzmann_const ) / hbar

# For subtracting from root_of_integral
a_const = np.log( ( 1.13 * hbar * debye_freq ) / ( boltzmann_const * transition_temp) )
# For simplifying function f.
b_const = ( hbar * debye_freq ) / ( 2 * boltzmann_const)


def f( coherence_length, temp ):
    # Defines the equation whose integral will have its roots found. Epsilon = coherence length. Delta = Gap energy.

    squareRoot = np.sqrt( coherence_length*coherence_length + gap_energy*gap_energy )
    return np.tanh( ( ( b_const / temp ) * squareRoot ) / squareRoot )


def integrate( coherence_length, temp ):
    # Integrates equation f with respect to E, between 0 and 1. 

    return integrate.quad( f, 0, 1, args = ( temp, ) )[0]


def root_of_integral( temp ):
    # Finds the roots of the integral with a guess of 0.01.

   return fsolve( integrate, 0.01, args = ( temp, ) )


def gap_energy_values( temp ):
    # Subtracts a_const from each root found, to obtain the gap_energy_values.

    return root_of_integral( temp ) - a_const
```

Comment: The error message given by the interpreter might be helpful?

Comment: Edited accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as has been mentioned in comments already (by @Hristo Iliev and @Pavel Annosov), `quad` [returns a tuple of stuff](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html). If you're assuming the integration has no problems, as you seem to be doing in Mathematica (which is not that good of an idea though), out of this tuple you only need the first element, which is supposed to be the integration result.

But this will only give you a single number, not a function of `T`. To get the latter, you'll need to define the corresponding function yourself, just like you did in Mathematica with your `\Delta[T_]:=...`

Here are a few bits to get you started:

```
def f(E, T):
    """To be integrated over T."""
    temp = np.sqrt(E * E + T * T)
    return np.tanh(1477.92 * temp) / temp


def gap(T):
    """Integration result: \Delta(T)"""
    return quad(f, 0, 1, args=(T, ))[0]  #NB: [0] select the 1st element of a tuple
```

Notice that you need to use the `args=(T,)` syntax to send the `T` parameter to the function being integrated: `quad` integrates over the first argument of the function, and it needs other arguments to be able to evaluate `f(E, T)`.

Now you can feed this `gap(T)` to `fsolve`, [which also expects a function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) (a `callable`, to be more precise).

On a slightly more general level, you should not be using numerical values of the Boltzmann constant, hbar and the like (even Mathematica complains!). What you should do instead, you should write your formulas in the dimensionless form: measure temperature in energy units (hence k_B = 1) etc, do appropriate substitutions in the integrals, so that you deal with dimensionless functions of dimensionless arguments --- and then make a computer handle those.

Comment: In physics one cannot have exponent of a quantity which is not dimensionless. The argument to the hyperbolic tangent is already dimensionless and would be the same, regardless if natural units are used or not. I would say that depending of how Mathematica evaluates `Tanh`, `1477.92*Sqrt[e^2+x^2]` goes beyond the acceptable argument of the double precision exponent. E.g. if it uses `Tanh[x] = (Exp[2x]-1)/(Exp[2x]+1)` then for `x >= 0.06` one has `1477.92*Sqrt[x^2+...] > 709.78` and the argument would be out of range for any `e` in `[[0,1]]`.

Comment: Yes, Hristo, 'natural units' might or might not be a better wording. I personally prefer to think of this as just making appropriate substitutions in the integrals etc --- before even touching a keyboard, but that's personal preference. Looks like we both agree that having in the code constants like kB=1.23e-23 is not right. As for the stability, I'd first wait for the OP to fix the issue with units, and then we'll be able to see if there's a genuine problem with numerical stability.

Comment: I agree that in general working with dimensionless quantities simplifies things and improves numerical stability. But not in this particular case.

Comment: Do you know what that magic number `1477` will turn into in proper units? I don't. And, once the integration's fixed, there's `fsolve` with it's `1e-23` as (I guess) a starting point.

Comment: The magic number 1477.92 is half of the ratio of the Debye cut-off energy and the thermal energy at ~0.1K. It would not change, no matter if proper or improper units are in use, unless the form of the integral is changed. As I don't intend to turn this into lecture on BCS theory for niobium, and given that `numpy.tanh()` evaluates just fine with large arguments, let's just wait and see what the OP would come up with. Not that he has provided any reasonable feedback on both his "Superconductivity with Python" questions thus far...

Comment: Cheers for help thus far, am new to Python and programming. This answer will be awarded the bounty for all it's taught thus far. But I am struggling with passing the `gap(T)` to `fsolve`. Have tried: `def roots(T):
 return fsolve(gap, args=(T,),0.0)` but, `NameError: name 'T' is not defined`

Comment: There's no need for a bounty really. Well, the error message is pretty clear: you need to define the value for `T` at the calling scope. The language is not operating with continuous variables, it needs numbers --- *you* need to define the number for `T`.

Comment: @8765674, if your current code matches that in the updated question, then you have `def integral(E): return integrate.quad(f,0,1,args=(T,))[0]`. Here `T` is undefined. But I guess the error actually comes from `pl.plot(T,gaps(T)*hbar*omegad)` in the main scope as `T` is not defined there.

Comment: The problem lies in trying to find the energy_gap in an equation with energy_gap in it. Energy gap always get sent back as undefined. Updated code:http://pastie.org/6347512 (Will update the trial to this in question also).

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
integral = (integrate.quad(lambda E: np.tanh(1477.92*np.sqrt(E**2+x**2))/np.sqrt(E**2+x**2), 0, 1)
```

has unbalanced parentheses:

```
integral = integrate.quad(lambda E: np.tanh(1477.92*np.sqrt(E**2+x**2))/np.sqrt(E**2+x**2), 0, 1)
```

Would be much easier to see if you broke it up, e.g.

```
x_values = arange(0.01, 0.1, 0.0001)

delta = []
for x in x_values:
    def fun(E):
        distance = np.sqrt(E * E + x * x)
        return np.tanh(1477.92 * distance) / distance

    integral = integrate.quad(fun, 0, 1)
    delta_val = fsolve(integral, 1e-23) - a
    delta.append(delta_val)

pl.plot(delta, x_values)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer thus far! This looks great, but I receive the error: http://pastie.org/private/frbdw2xsurchme6s5czk1w

Comment: This should probably be a separate question, but `integrate.quad` returns an tuple of stuff, and `fsolve` expects a function. Since I'm bad at math and can't parse your mathematica program, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: In your case `integral` is probably a pair of numbers: `(result, absoluteError)`. Did you expect the `integrate` to return a function?

Comment: You have to define a function that evaluates the integral and pass that function to the roots finder `fsolve`.